# getting the delay/lag of Ultrasonic pulse velocity matlab

Tags: matlab

I am currently doing a thesis that needs Ultrasonic pulse velocity(UPV). UPV can easily be attained via the machines but the data we acquired didn't have UPV so we are tasked to get it manually.

Essentially in the data we have 2 channels, one for the transmitter transducer and another for a receiver transducer.

We need to get the time from wave from the transmitter is emitted and the time it arrives to the receiver.

Using matlab, I've tried `finddelay` and `xcorr` but doesnt quite get the right result.

Here is a picture of the points I would want to get. The plot is of the transmitter(blue) and receiver(red)

[image: Example input]

So I am trying to find the two points in the picture but with the aid of matlab. The two would determine the time and further the UPV.
I am relatively a new MATLAB user so your help would be of great assistance.

Here is the code I have tried

```
[cc, lags] = xcorr(signal1,signal2); 
d2 = -(lags(cc == max(cc))) / Fs;
```

@xenoclast hi there! so far the code i used are these.

```
close all
clc
Fs = input('input Fs = ');
T = 1/Fs;
L = input('input L = ');
t = (0:L-1)*T;
time = transpose(t);
i = input('input number of steploads = ');
% construct test sequences
%dataupv is the signal1 & datathesis is the signal2
for m=1:i
y1 = (dataupv(:,m) - mean(dataupv(:,m))) / std(dataupv(:,m));
y2 = (datathesis(:,m) - mean(datathesis(:,m))) / std(datathesis(:,m));
offset = 166;
tt = time;
% correlate the two sequences
[cc, lags] = xcorr(y2, y1,);
% find the in4dex of the maximum
[maxval, maxI] = max(cc);
[minval, minI] = min(cc);
% use that index to obtain the lag in samples
lagsamples(m,1) = lags(maxI);
lagsamples2(m,1) = lags(minI);
% plot again without timebase to verify visually
end
```

the resulting value is off by 70 samples compared to when i visually inspect the waves. the lag resulted in 244 but visually it should be 176 here are the data(there are 19 sets of data but i only used the 1st column) https://www.dropbox.com/s/ng5uq8f7oyap0tq/datatrans-dec-2014.xlsx?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/1x7en0x7elnbg42/datarec-dec-2014.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: essentially i am just trying to find the points when the signals began.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It would help a lot to add to your question the code you've tried so far and the results - this helps to target the answers. For my money though `xcorr` is the way to go - these two signals will correlate nicely - so it's possible that the problem lies in the implementation. The index point of the peak in the correlation output needs to be offset by an amount related to the length of the two input sequences, if you haven't already corrected for this then it's likely that when you do the result will be satisfactory.

Comment: thank you for your attention! 
ive been looking into this code:

[cc, lags] = xcorr(signal1,signal2);                        
d2 = -(lags(cc == max(cc))) / Fs;

i am not sure if the code above was the right one
though, the result was larger than expected so im guessing something is wrong.
it would be great if you could guide me in the steps to do:)

Comment: I've made a stab at it. I've also copied your code into the question to make it easier for other people to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code doesn't specify `Fs` so I don't know for sure but I'm guessing that it's an issue of sample rate(s). All the examples of cross correlation start out by constructing test sequences according to a specific sample rate that they usually call `Fs`, not to be confused with the frequency of the test tone, which you may see called `Fc`.

If you construct the test signals in terms of `Fs` and `Fc` then this works fine but when you get real data from an instrument they often give you the data and the timebase as two vectors, so you have to work out the sample rate from the timebase. This may not be the same as the operating frequency or the components of the signal, so confusion is easy here.

But the sample rate is only required in the second part of the problem, where you work out the offset in time. First you have to get the offset in samples and that's a lot easier to verify.

Your example will give you the offset in samples if you remove the '/ Fs' term and you can verify it by plotting the two signals without a timebase and inspecting the sample positions.

I'm sure you've looked at dozens of examples but here's one that attempts to not confuse the issue by tying it to sample rates - you'll note that nowhere is it specified what the 'sample rate' is, it's just tied to samples (although if you treat the 5 in the `y1` definition as a frequency in Hz then you will be able to infer one).

```
% construct test sequences
offset = 23;
tt = 0:0.01:1;
y1 = sin(2*pi*5*tt);
y2 = 0.8 * [zeros(1, offset) y1];

figure(1); clf; hold on
plot(tt, y1)
plot(tt, y2(1:numel(tt)), 'r')

% correlate the two sequences
[cc, lags] = xcorr(y2, y1);

figure(2); clf;
plot(cc)

% find the index of the maximum
[maxval, maxI] = max(cc);

% use that index to obtain the lag in samples
lagsamples = lags(maxI);

% plot again without timebase to verify visually
figure(3); clf; hold on
plot(y1)
plot(y2, 'r')
plot([offset offset], [-1 1], 'k:')
```

Once you've got the offset in samples you can probably deduce the required conversion factor, but if you have timebase data from the instrument then the inverse of the diff of any two consecutive entries will give it you.

UPDATE

When you correlate the two signals you can visualise it as overlaying them and summing the product of corresponding elements. This gives you a single value. Then you move one signal by a sample and do it again. Continue until you have done it at every possible arrangement of the two signals.

The value obtained at each step is the correlation, but the 'lag' is computed starting with one signal all the way over to the left and the other overlapping by only one sample. You slide the second signal all the way over until it's only overlapping the other end by a sample. Hence the number of values returned by the correlation is related to the length of both the original signals, and relating any given point in the correlation output, such as the max value, to the arrangement of the two signals that produced it requires you to do a calculation involving those lengths. The `xcorr` function makes this easier by outputting the `lags` variable, which tracks the alignment of the two signals. People may also talk about this as an offset so watch out for that.

Comment: The Fs is 5000000 and L is 5001  and  but I have a few questions:   
first, how is offset worked out and how do i verify it? and isnt offset the difference between the two points i have shown in the picture i provided? thank you :)

Comment: @ronster Yes the offset is the difference between the two points, or any two corresponding points. You could measure this difference in samples or time. The reason it's not simple to work out is because of the 'sliding window' - see update to question for that bit.

Comment: is there a way for matlab to get this offset?  i am kinda confused.. how does the offset and delay differ from one another?

Comment: There is the sliding window offset, which is varied to provide the correlation results. this offset is returned in the `lags` variable, the second output of `xcorr`. The delay between your two signals is a specific offset that you can recover by looking at the lags, specifially at the index at the maximum value of the correlation output.

Comment: ive added some details on the question